# Show add_meta_box by selecting a specific category

Tags: plugin-development, categories, metabox

In my plugin I want to display an add_meta_box under the WYSISWYG in the new post page, which is no problem and works fine.
But the box should only appear when a specific category (example: category with id = 5) is selected, otherwise it is not visible.

How can this be achieved?

Edit as requested in the comments here is my jquery:

```
$script = "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $('#metabox_sectionid').hide();
                    $('#in-category-".CATEGORY."').is(':checked') ? $('#metabox_sectionid').show() : $('#emetabox_sectionid').hide();
                    $('#in-category-".CATEGORY."').click(function() {
                        $('#metabox_sectionid').toggle(this.checked);
                    });
                });
            </script>";
        echo $script;
```

BR & Thanks,
mybecks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:
get the ID's of the attached categories and wrap your add_meta_box function inside a simple test against your defined cat ID.

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'is_in_cat_example');

function is_in_cat_example() {
    global $post;
    $category = '5'; // can be an array of ID's as well

    if ( in_category( $category, $post ) ) {
    add_meta_box(...);
        }

}
```

Comment: An additional note: If you want it to appear on selection, you will need to do that via jQuery, the way this answer stands, it will take a save then a page reload to get the box to appear. Good answer though, +1

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I need. Now adding the jQuery part, to make it smoother. :)

Comment: cool, would be nice if you can post your solution for the jquery part.

Comment: @ungestaltbar i've updated my question with the jquery part. hope that helps.